# About the Lipschitz property of stratified analytic, arc-analytic and semianalytic map

Tags: real-algebraic-geometry

Let $f:U\to V$ be a $1:1$ map between open subsets $U,V\subset\mathbb{C}^N$ such that $f$ and its inverse $f^{-1}$ are both arc-analytic, semianalytic and piece-wisely real analytic with respect to some complex analytic stratifications.

My question is: Is $f$ locally Lipschitz at every point of $U$?

Comment: I am not 100% sure I understand the terminology, but would not the following be a counterexample: $z\to z^2$, where $U\subset \mathbb C^1$ is the domain $Re(z)>0, |z|<1$ ($V$ is the disk $|z|<1$ minus the interval $-(i,0)$)? It seems to me that this map satisfies all the conditions, however $\sqrt z$ is not a Lipschitz function at $0$. If you don't ask $V$ to be bounded, one can take $f=\frac{1}{1-z}$ and $U$ the disk $|z|<1$?

Comment: Thx Dmitri for the counterexamples. I made a mistake on the qustion. I should ask whether $f$ is locally Lipschitz instead of (global) Lipschitz.

Comment: Thanks for explaining. Just out of curiosity, what would be a non-trivial example of such a map?

Comment: The answer seems to be yes. Since f is arc-analytic and semianalytic, it is locally blowup analytic. So it has to be locally Lipschitz. Am I right? By the way, I don't know an explicit non-trivial example yet. The paper of Parusinski-Paunescu on the arc-wise analytic trivialization of an analytic singularity show that the map discribed in the question usually appear near analytic singularities